# Calculate the difference between Multidimensional ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, difference

I have two ArrayLists saved as Collections.

ArrayList A contains

```
[[lgi09, Verantworlichter], [mne09, Developer], [root, Verantworlichter]]
```

ArrayList B Contains

```
[[lgi09, Verantwortlicher], [lgi09, Developer], [ltr09, Bereitschafter], [fmo09, Bereitschafter]]
```

I have to compare ArrayLst A and ArrayLst B . The result ArrayList should contain the List which does not exist in ArrayList A. ArrayList result should be

```
[[lgi09, Developer], [ltr09, Bereitschafter], [fmo09,Bereitschafter]]
```

I already tried it like this:

```
public static Collection findDifferences(Collection base, Collection extension){
    base.removeAll(extension);  
    return base;
}
```

but this returns the whole base list without comparing.

Comment: Have you tried anything. If yes, please share.

Comment: The element is `String`?

Comment: @AmanChhabra updated it

Comment: @user6690200 one single element is a String. Yes, but they are contained in Arraylists that contains all ArrayLists of those String elements

Comment: try remove duplicate first like `arrayListA.removeAll(arrayListB)` and then merge two arrar  `arrayListA.addAll(arrayListB)`. Last thing remain is Short `collections.sort(arrayListA);` would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeAll` removes items relying on the result of the `equals` method. Easiest way is:

1. Use an object as data for your ArrayLists (not sure if you already did this)
2. Implement `equals` method in such object, returning true only if every field  matches

**EDIT**

Something like:

```
public class Data {
    private String code, word;
    public Data(String code, String word){
        this.code = code;
        this.word = word;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        Data d = (Data) o;
        return this.code.equals(d.code) && this.word.equals(d.word);
    }
}
```

I'm aware that the above implementation  is not perferct, but it is just to give an idea.

Your ArrayLists have to be built like this:

```
Collection a = new ArrayList();
a.add(new Data("lgi09", "Verantworlichter"));
a.add(new Data("mne09", "Developer"));
a.add(new Data("root", "Verantworlichter"));
```

You could then implicitly use the `equals` calling `removeAll`:

```
public static Collection findDifferences(Collection base, Collection extension){
    base.removeAll(extension);  
    return base;
}
```

Note that in this example I've used `String` as type for `Data` fields, but you could use anything.

Comment: can you please explain this further?